# Pass a class subroutine as a callback

Tags: perl, anyevent

I am using a module that takes callbacks (AnyEvent::Socket).
I am trying to pass a class subroutine as a callback but nothing is working
example:

```
tcp_server undef, $self->port,\$self->handle_connection
```

It just does not work, it complaints about undefined variables. if I pass the function as a anonymous subroutine it works

Comment: \&$self->handle_connection perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a anonymous function which calls object method,

```
sub{ $self->handle_connection }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`curry`](http://metacpan.org/pod/curry) module was built for this sort of thing

```
use curry;

tcp_server undef, $self->port, $self->curry::handle_connection
```